# Odoo crashes when creating several records at the same time

Tags: odoo

I have created a method where I import a csv file and I create new records with the data it contains. The method works with as csv with around 1000 lines. (The method can create around 1000 new records), but when the csv file have more than 1200 lines, Odoo server crashes and I have to restart the server. Here is my method and the odoo log

```
   @api.multi
    @profile
    def action_import_csv(self):
        cuenta = 0
        self._chequear_extension_csv(self.archivo_filename)
        res = base64.b64decode(self.archivo)
        text = res.decode("UTF-8")
        reader = csv.DictReader(io.StringIO(text))
        brigadista = self.env['utepda_brigadas.brigadista']
        brigada = self.env['utepda_brigadas.brigada']
        brigada_cr = self.env.cr

        brigadista_brigada = self.env['utepda_brigadas.brigadista_brigada']
        count = 0
        campos = [
            'BRIGADA', 'NOMBRE', 'CEDULA', 'CARGO', 'JORNALES', 'COSTO_JORNADA'
        ]

        rows = list(reader)
        totalrows = len(rows)
        print("La cantidad de filas es {}".format(totalrows))
        for index,row in enumerate(rows):
            print("Index -> {}  -> {}".format(index,row))
            if count == 0:
                count = 1
                self._chequear_campos_csv(campos, row.keys())
            else:
                codigo_brigada = row['BRIGADA']
                nombre = row['NOMBRE']
                cedula = row['CEDULA'].replace('-', '')
                cargo = row['CARGO']
                dias_trabajados = row['JORNALES']
                total_jornada = row['COSTO_JORNADA']
                fecha = self.fecha
                total = int(dias_trabajados) * int(total_jornada)
                existe_brigadista = brigadista.search([['cedula', '=', cedula]],limit=1)
                
                brigada_actual = brigada.search([['codigo', '=', codigo_brigada]],limit=1)
                #brigada_cr.execute(
                #    "SELECT id FROM public.utepda_brigada_brigada WHERE codigo=%s"
                #    % codigo_brigada)
                #res = brigada_cr.fetchone()
                #brigada_actual = brigada.search([['codigo', '=', codigo_brigada]],
                #limit=1)
                #brigada_actual = res[0]
                if not existe_brigadista.id:
                    new = {
                        'name':
                        nombre,
                        'cedula':
                        cedula,
                        'cargo':
                        cargo,
                        'estado':
                        "nuevo",
                        'brigada_ids': [(0, _, {
                            'fecha': fecha,
                            'dias_trabajados': dias_trabajados,
                            'total': total,
                            'brigada_id': brigada_actual.id
                        })]
                    }
                    nuevo_brigadista = brigadista.create(new)
                    if nuevo_brigadista.id:
                        cuenta = cuenta+1
                    print("""{} Se ha insertado el brigadista {} con nombre {}""".format(cuenta,nuevo_brigadista.id,
                                                                            nuevo_brigadista.name))
                    #existe_brigadista = existe_brigadista[0]

                else:
                    existe_brigadista.write({
                        'estado':
                        "reportado",
                        'brigada_ids': [(0, _, {
                            'fecha': fecha,
                            'dias_trabajados': dias_trabajados,
                            'total': total,
                            'brigada_id': brigada_actual.id
                        })]
                    })

        fecha_format = datetime.strftime(self.fecha, '%m/%Y')
        no_reportados = brigadista.search(
            [['fecha_ultimo_reporte', '!=', fecha_format]])
        no_reportados.write({'estado': "no_reportado"})

        return {
            'type': 'ir.actions.client',
            'tag': 'reload',
        }
```

Here is the Odoo log

```
2020-11-04 11:44:23,285 15044 WARNING odoo odoo.service.server: Thread <Thread(odoo.service.http.request.140355723687680, started 140355723687680)> virtual real time limit (152/120s) reached. 
2020-11-04 11:44:23,289 15044 INFO odoo odoo.service.server: Dumping stacktrace of limit exceeding threads before reloading 
2020-11-04 11:44:23,520 15044 INFO odoo odoo.tools.misc: 
# Thread: <Thread(odoo.service.http.request.140355723687680, started 140355723687680)> (db:odoo) (uid:2) (url:http://localhost:8069/web/dataset/call_button)
File: "/home/ernesto/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.5.86806/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/no_wheels/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydev_bundle/pydev_monkey.py", line 823, in __call__
  ret = self.original_func(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
File: "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 884, in _bootstrap
  self._bootstrap_inner()
File: "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
  self.run()
File: "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
  self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File: "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 654, in process_request_thread
  self.finish_request(request, client_address)
File: "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 364, in finish_request
  self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
File: "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 724, in __init__
  self.handle()
File: "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 228, in handle
  rv = BaseHTTPRequestHandler.handle(self)
File: "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/server.py", line 418, in handle
  self.handle_one_request()
File: "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 263, in handle_one_request
  return self.run_wsgi()
File: "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 205, in run_wsgi
  execute(self.server.app)
File: "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 193, in execute
  application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
File: "/home/ernesto/odoo12/odoo/service/server.py", line 434, in app
  return self.app(e, s)
File: "/home/ernesto/odoo12/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 142, in application
  return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)
File: "/home/ernesto/odoo12/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 117, in application_unproxied
  result = odoo.http.root(environ, start_response)
File: "/home/ernesto/odoo12/odoo/http.py", line 1320, in __call__
  return self.dispatch(environ, start_response)
File: "/home/ernesto/odoo12/odoo/http.py", line 1293, in __call__
  return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)
File: "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 599, in __call__
  return self.app(environ, start_response)
File: "/home/ernesto/odoo12/odoo/http.py", line 1488, in dispatch
  result = ir_http._dispatch()
File: "/home/ernesto/odoo12/addons/auth_signup/models/ir_http.py", line 19, in _dispatch
  return super(Http, cls)._dispatch()
File: "/home/ernesto/odoo12/addons/web_editor/models/ir_http.py", line 22, in _dispatch
  return super(IrHttp, cls)._dispatch()
File: "/home/ernesto/odoo12/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_http.py", line 203, in _dispatch
  result = request.dispatch()
File: "/home/ernesto/odoo12/odoo/http.py", line 698, in dispatch
  result = self._call_function(**self.params)
File: "/home/ernesto/odoo12/odoo/http.py", line 346, in _call_function
  return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
File: "/home/ernesto/odoo12/odoo/service/model.py", line 98, in wrapper
  return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
File: "/home/ernesto/odoo12/odoo/http.py", line 339, in checked_call
  result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
File: "/home/ernesto/odoo12/odoo/http.py", line 941, in __call__
  return self.method(*args, **kw)
File: "/home/ernesto/odoo12/odoo/http.py", line 519, in response_wrap
  response = f(*args, **kw)
File: "/home/ernesto/odoo12/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 966, in call_button
  action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})
File: "/home/ernesto/odoo12/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 954, in _call_kw
  return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
File: "/home/ernesto/odoo12/odoo/api.py", line 759, in call_kw
  return _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
File: "/home/ernesto/odoo12/odoo/api.py", line 746, in _call_kw_multi
  result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
File: "<decorator-gen-127>", line 2, in action_import_csv
File: "/home/ernesto/odoo12/odoo/tools/profiler.py", line 128, in _odooProfile
  result = method(*args, **kwargs)
File: "/home/ernesto/odoo12/extra_addons/utepda_brigadas/models/model_wizard.py", line 81, in action_import_csv
  nuevo_brigadista = brigadista.create(new)
File: "<decorator-gen-111>", line 2, in create
File: "/home/ernesto/odoo12/odoo/api.py", line 461, in _model_create_multi
  return create(self, [arg])
File: "/home/ernesto/odoo12/addons/mail/models/mail_thread.py", line 278, in create
  thread._message_log(body=_('%s created') % doc_name)
File: "/home/ernesto/odoo12/addons/mail/models/mail_thread.py", line 2230, in _message_log
  message = self.env['mail.message'].sudo().create(message_values)
File: "<decorator-gen-107>", line 2, in create
File: "/home/ernesto/odoo12/odoo/api.py", line 440, in _model_create_single
  return create(self, arg)
File: "/home/ernesto/odoo12/addons/mail/models/mail_message.py", line 990, in create
  message = super(Message, self).create(values)
File: "<decorator-gen-3>", line 2, in create
File: "/home/ernesto/odoo12/odoo/api.py", line 461, in _model_create_multi
  return create(self, [arg])
File: "/home/ernesto/odoo12/odoo/models.py", line 3583, in create
  records = self._create(data_list)
File: "/home/ernesto/odoo12/odoo/models.py", line 3669, in _create
  col_val = field.convert_to_column(val, self, stored)
File: "/home/ernesto/odoo12/odoo/fields.py", line 1555, in convert_to_column
  strip_classes=self.strip_classes)
File: "/home/ernesto/odoo12/odoo/tools/mail.py", line 227, in html_sanitize
  cleaned = cleaner.clean_html(src)
File: "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/lxml/html/clean.py", line 517, in clean_html
  doc = fromstring(html)
File: "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/lxml/html/__init__.py", line 876, in fromstring
  doc = document_fromstring(html, parser=parser, base_url=base_url, **kw)
File: "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/lxml/html/__init__.py", line 762, in document_fromstring
  value = etree.fromstring(html, parser, **kw) 
2020-11-04 11:44:23,522 15044 INFO odoo odoo.service.server: Initiating server reload
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably timing out due to the sheer amount of records. Add the following to your config file, but play around with the settings to see what works best for you.

```
--limit-time-real 10000

limit_time_real = 480
```

I would also increase workers if you can to not slow down the Odoo

https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/setup/deploy.html#builtin-server